# use of noun then comma and そして

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I dont understand this sentence:

> Action servletは、リクエストのリクエストURLと対応するPATH、そしてACTIONクラスの完全修飾名を定義しているACTIONMAPPINGの集合によりなりたっています。

Does this mean: "the collection 'action'mapping, which defines the fully qualified domain name consists of the path which deals with the the request url"?

Particuarly confusing to me is the function of apparent noun (なになにと対応するPATH）followed by comma, and a そして.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence appeared ambiguous and poorly-written to me. After looking at some articles about Struts, I think this sentence should mean:

> An action servlet consists of a collection of action mappings, each of which defines *a)* the path that corresponds to the request URL of a request, and *b)* the fully qualified name of an action class.

- リクエストのリクエストURLと対応するPATH: a path that corresponds to the [request URL of a request (object)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI()). Note that と after リクエストURL is not "and" but "to" as in "A**と**対応するB" ("B that corresponds *to* A")
- ACTIONクラスの完全修飾名: the fully qualified name of an action class. 完全修飾名
  is FQN, which is FQCN in this context. It's not to be confused with FQDN.
- 「リクエストのリクエストURLと対応するPATH、そしてACTIONクラスの完全修飾名」 is the object of 定義している. Here **そして** is just another way to say および ("and").

  > 青い空、そして青い海!  The blue sky, *and* the blue ocean!
- 「クエストのリクエストURLと対応するPATH、そしてACTIONクラスの完全修飾名を定義している」 is a long relative clause that modifies "ACTIONMAPPING".
- I don't know why PATH and ACTIONMAPPING are capitalized like this. Was this machine-translated, or was this sentence made by someone who doesn't care cases and spaces?

---

This sentence describes the following structure in a configuration XML file of Struts:

```
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/page1" type="com.example.Page1Action" />
    <action path="/page2" type="com.example.Page2Action" />
</action-mappings>
```

Here each `<action>` element forms a "mapping", where:

- The `path` attribute defines リクエストのリクエストURLと対応するPATH.
- The `type` attribute defines ACTIONクラスの完全修飾名.

Comment: I must say again that the sentence in question is ambiguous if we don't refer to the documentation. Before I read some articles about Struts, the other answers by mackygoo and Philippe seemed legit...

Comment: Hence the importance of fuller context and knowledge of the subject matter! Good find, @naruto. As for the capitalized words, I run into it all the time and privately refer to it as random capitalizationitis -- the disease of Japanese 理系出身 writers to capitalize words left in English in the text willy-nilly. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence use an A and B, as well as C type of construction.

To break it down a little:

The middle part breaks down as:

A:リクエストのリクエストURL

と

B: 対応するPATH、

そして

C: ACTIONクラスの完全修飾名を定義しているACTIONMAPPING

の集合 -> applies the set of A+B+C

And the sentence overall is
Action servletは、"the collection of A+B+C" によりなりたっています。

One more tip: 対応 also translates as corresponding in some contexts.

Hope that's enough to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

> Action servletは、リクエストのリクエストURLと対応するPATH、そしてACTIONクラスの完全修飾名を定義しているACTIONMAPPINGの集合によりなりたっています。

Action servletは、
リクエストのリクエストURLと対応するPATH
と
ACTIONクラスの完全修飾名を定義しているACTIONMAPPING
の集合
によりなりたっています。

Action servlet consists of a set/collection (集合) of PATH and ACTIONMAPPING;
where PATH corresponds to the request URL of REQUEST,
and
ACTIONMSPPING defines the fully qualified domain name of ACTION CLASS.

---

According to the explanation [here](http://www.techscore.com/tech/Java/ApacheJakarta/Struts/1-3/)

> ActionServletは呼び出されると、その時のURLとStruts設定ファイルに基づいて実行するActionクラスを決定します。

Because the explanation in Japanese is ambiguous, it could be interpreted in two ways as:

1. When ActionServlet is called, it decides the URL at that time and Action Class which is executed based on the Struts configuration file.
2. When ActionServlet is called, it decides Action Class which is executed based on the URL at that time and the Struts configuration file.

> ＜struts-config＞内の＜action-mapping＞が、URLと呼び出されるActionクラスの設定を記述する部分です。具体的な設定はタグで行われ「path」属性でURL、「type」属性で呼び出されるActionクラスが指定されます。

＜action-mapping＞ in ＜struts-config＞ is the place where URL and Action class to be called are described. More precise configuration is defined by ＜action＞ tag, where URL is defined by "path" attribute and Action class to be called is defined by "type" attribute.

Hope it helps.

Comment: 「『パス』と『クラス名を定義しているマッピング』の二者の集合」なのではなく、「『パス』と『クラス名』の二者を定義している『マッピング』の集合」じゃないですかね。まあ文からだけだとどちらとも解釈できる（というかmackygooさんやPhilippeさんの解釈の方が素直だとすら思える）ので、ドキュメント読まないとどうしようもありませんが。